# Can I compile the Addthis JS file into my own local JS?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, addthis

When you add Addthis share buttons to your site, Addthis provides this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true}</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=MYADDTHISPROFILEID"></script>
```

In this case "MYADDTHISPROFILEID" represents my public ID that Addthis generated for my Profile.

I want to reduce the amount of requests I'm making so I'd like to use Grunt to compile the Addthis widget script into the rest of my JS. Is that possible?

Or is the Public ID required? Is it the ID that associates my website with my Addthis account? I want to be sure I can still track analytics.

Comment: they might update the script often and you would miss updates if you exported the hosted copy.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we do not recommend compiling addthis_widget.js into your code since we update that file fairly often with fixes/updates.  If you were to compile it into your code, you would be stuck on an older version and you wouldn't get updates.  If it makes you feel any better, our assets are highly cached, so they really shouldn't add too much load for your users since all the js/css files are probably already available on their browser.